# NuGet: How do I report a defect to Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have found a situation where NuGet Package Manager and nuget.exe do not perform restore with the same results.

I would like to report this in hopes that they might fix it.

I can share the nupkg and the test case if anyone wants to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NuGet: How do I report a defect to Microsoft?

You can report a issue to Microsoft via **Send Feedback** in Visual Studio:

[image]

Alternatively, you can report this issue on the GitHub: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues

Besides, if possible, you can also share the nupkg, the test case and detail steps here, I believe that there will be a lot of communities interested in this issue.